# Horizon waiting for Stellar-core to sync

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, history, peers

I have built `stellar-core` and `horizon` instances from source on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I managed to make them work for the test-net, yet now, whilst trying to configure `stellar-core.cfg` for the public network, I am unable to connect to peers.

I have tried multiple `.cfg` specifications, but always end up with issues related to the Overlay component of `stellar-core`.

By using the following `.cfg` file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon/master/pubnet/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg

I get the following log output:

`[Overlay WARNING] 2018-06-21T13:34:44.778 GCZGU [Overlay ERROR] TCPPeer::drop shutdown socket failed: Transport endpoint is not connected [TCPPeer.cpp:195]`

What could be the issue here? I looked int othe `TCPPeer.cpp` file, and that was not as well documented as I had expected since line 195 only referred to printing an error message without explaining where the error was generated.

**Edit**
With an alternative `stellar-core.cfg` I ended up with the following log:

`2018-06-21T12:11:35.429 GDMPG [Overlay TRACE] OverlayManagerImpl tick [OverlayManagerImpl.cpp:288]`

...

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**
After letting `stellar-core` and `horizon` run for a while with the first configuration (prior to Edit, in other words the Container solution), eventually bucket entries where added. Yet, after a while `horizon` asked me to re-create the horizon PSQL database since I had not done this prior to evolving to the public network.

After re-creating the PSQL database for Horizon, and re-initializing it with `horizon db init`, the `stellar-core` database with `stellar-core --newdb` I am unable to fetch the History buckets from [the Stellar core history bucket repository](http://history.stellar.org) available at:

http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz

I am not sure why this happens, since it appeared to be just fine yesterday. As is noticeable, the URL gives a 404 error. Anyone got some advice on defining the bucket directories correctly? Or are the history repositories down during certain time periods?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same issue with the `testnet` second day in row. But after a 30 min of sync up attempts, I was able to connect to the testnet.
I think it's something wrong with the network on the validators side.

Comment: I think the issue arises because Stellar-core has to sync, as indicated by Horizon. Right now, I am getting several `[Bucket INFO] Bucket-apply: committed xxxxx entries`, after I let both instances of Horizon and Stellar-core run for a few minutes. 

It has been like that for a while now, so I am leaving it at that for a while to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: `Horizon` is just like a plugin of `Core`, which should not affect the behaviour of Core. You may ignore the Horizon part for the moment, as your issue is with Core.

---

It seems to me that you might have kept the testnet history files of Core, which could mislead Core which was trying to sync with public-network.

As you first had the testnet up-running, it was holding and generating new testnet data (DB records & history files). Later, you tried to change it to the public network, but those old data were not deleted, which could be problematic.

---

My suggestion would be:

First, stop your stellar-core application.

Second, with your new config for public network, do `stellar-core --newdb` to reintialize the DB part.

Then, delete everything related to the testnet history files `/opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}`.

Finally, do `stellar-core --newhist cache`, to prepare history files for public network (newhist "cache", as I read that you use `[HISTORY.cache]`), and you can start stellar-core application.

p.s. For public network, [it might be better to choose validators from here.](https://dashboard.stellar.org) At the time of post, it seems those "Stronghold" nodes might be problematic, and you may try others.

---

As I have heard of, many people indicated that it takes "some" time to start catching-up to the gigantic test-net / public live-net. Such time varies from minutes to ten hours. So...maybe do all the re-intialization steps, and then sit back and wait, for up to 10 hours.

If it persists, please provide more detailed steps of how you did it...